# modify first n columns and print the rest of the row

Tags: awk

I want to modify the first two columns and print the rest

```
col1  col2  col3 col4 ...
```

What I tried so far:

```
cat file | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$2+1;  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){printf " %s", $i} printf "\n"}' | head
```

Which displays the results like this:

```
col1   col2   col2+1
col3   col4   ...
```

However I want the results on a single line:

```
col1  col2  col2+1  col3 col4 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
cat file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$ awk '{$2=$2 OFS $2+1}1' OFS='\t' file
1    2    3    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but here you see how to modify the two first column and then print all.

```
awk '{$1="new1";$2="new2"}1' file
new1 new2 col3 col4
```